# MongoDB grouping task - multiple groups, conditions

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

My goal is to get all 'student' documents that belong to 'classes'
that have at least one student of grade "blue" and at least one 
of grade "red".

I am inclined to simply do a sequence of queries in Python (pymongo), tackling the task directly.

I wonder if there is some clever aggregation pipeline that I could use!

Given:

Classes collection:

```
{ class_id: 'a' }
{ class_id: 'b' }
```

Students collection:

```
{ class_id: 'a',
grade: 'blue' }

{class_id: 'a',
grade: 'red' }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use :

- a `$group` to group by `class_id` and `$push` all grade in an array so we can deduce easily in the next step which class "contains" `blue`. Preserve the current document with [`$$ROOT`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.ROOT) because we'll need the students that match the `class_id`
- a `$match` to match only classes that have grade `blue` in it
- an `$unwind` to remove the array of students generated by previous `$$ROOT`
- a `$project` to reorganize your document nicely

Query would be :

```
db.students.aggregate([{
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$class_id",
        "grades": { "$push": "$grade" },
        "students": { "$push": "$$ROOT" }
    }
}, {
    "$match": {
        "grades": { "$all": ["blue","red"] }
    }
}, {
    "$unwind": "$students"
}, {
    "$project": {
        "_id": "$students._id",
        "class_id": "$students.class_id",
        "grade": "$students.grade",
    }
}])
```

If you need to match other color than ["blue","red"] you can add more in the `$match` aggregation (`$in: ["blue","red","yellow"]`)

For implementing it in PyMongo, it is very straightforward :

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import pprint

db = MongoClient().testDB

pipeline = [ <the_aggregation_query_here> ]

pprint.pprint(list(db.students.aggregate(pipeline)))
```

Additionnaly, to match only students that belong to `classes` collection, perform a [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) and match those that are not empty. Add the following at the aggregation query :

```
{
    $lookup: {
        from: "classes",
        localField: "class_id",
        foreignField: "class_id",
        as: "class"
    }
}, {
    $match: {
        "class": { $not: { $size: 0 } }
    }
}
```